# Using WebKitGTK+ on Centos 5.8?

Tags: webkit, gtk, centos, centos5

I'm trying to build an embedded simple web browser for an embedded device and I've decided to use WebKit / WebKitGTK+. However, our device uses a Linux environment somewhat based on CentOS 5.8. I haven't been able to find any RPMS or mention of support for WebKit / WebKitGTK+ for CentOS 5.8 while doing several web searches.

Does anybody know if it's possible to build an older version of WebKitGTK+ such as 1.2.6-2.el6_0 which works well on CentOS 6.3? Are any RPMS available for CentOS 5.8?

The goal here is to be able to run a relatively current, at least 1.2.6 version of WebKitGTk on CentOS 5.8

**Note: I was able to sort everything out. Just took a long time compiling all of the dependencies in the correct order with the correct options. I was able to get WebKitGTK 1.6.0 running on Centos 5.8.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the compilation options you should be able to compile the dependencies in an isolated directory. With each library you typically use the `--prefix` option to specify the destination. Then when compiling something that depends on that library, you typically have an option to specify where to look for that library - something like `--with-libraryname=/path/to/library`. You want to check `./configure --help` of each thing you're compiling to get the correct options.

It'll be quite a bit of work, but you should be able to compile everything you need into an isolated directory without replacing anything on the system. I would highly recommend you avoid doing this in root to ensure you have the right options.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have any problems building an old version of webkit if you can install the older versions of libraries that it requires.

If you have older or newer versions of GTK+ etc installed than the old version of webkit requires it may need quite a bit of porting to compile.

I'm not aware of any RPMs that meet your requirements

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that even the oldest version of WebKitGTK require a newer version of GTK and glib than we have on our linux environment on over 50K devices in the field. It's nearly impossible to convince my boss to go through the hassle of updating our embedded devices linux environment.

Comment: Ok,then you only have one option: backport the version of webkit to your old GTK. I know from experience that it's possible to backport a relatively modern webkit to  at least gtk 2.14, it might be possible to go earlier.

Comment: I'm attempting to follow the instructions on Linux From Scratch to build all of WebKitGTK on Centos 5.8. Hundreds of required packages, but making progress.

Comment: Yeah, and WebKit itself takes an age to compile once you get all the dependencies. Good luck